# Calculate proportions from biased datasets

Tags: inference, bias

I have two datasets coming from two different store selling computers.

**Datasets :**

The datasets are about people bringing their old computer to buy a new one, and has 4 columns.

- Old computer's model
- Old OS (Windows or Mac)
- New computer's model
- New OS

**The question :**

I need to provide the percentage of people going from an OS to another, and the decomposition of the brands.

For example, among the people which bought a new computer, 20% went from a windows computer to a mac. And these people had at 80% went from model A to model B.

**The Problem :**

My problem is that one of the dataset is bigger than the other and biased toward mac (because it's an affiliated so more chance to find people buying a mac).

How do I infer the proportions explained above knowing these bias.

Comment: Your problem looks easy: If you truly want to "provide" the percentage, then simply do so: this is a matter of *descriptive statistics,* not inference.  It's unclear how you could perform valid inferences from these data.

Comment: The goal would be to have a "national" view of computer churn using the dataset from the two stores. Just "providing" the percentage gave 95% of people buying Mac's. I was searching on my side if there was "weighting" methods to have a more accurate percentages, that's why i talked about inference. sorry if it was misleading

Comment: That sounds like an unwarranted extrapolation, unless you have convincing evidence that these two stores must have the same characteristics as all stores nationally.  That seems unlikely.  And even if that assumption can be supported, probabilistic methods of statistical inference are inapplicable.

Comment: Can you explain why they are inapplicable ? I Understand the point for the extrapolation of the percentage who bought a mac or a windows. But Can i extrapolate the second part, saying when buying a mac, XX% choose model A ?

Comment: You have no valid statistical basis to suppose that the experience of these stores is anything like that of stores nationally.  You may *assume* that, of course, but such an assumption (a) likely is not supported with data (since you haven't mentioned having anything like that) and (b) is not quantitative, because it does not permit you to measure how much your sample-based estimates might deviate from the real values.